# files can be drawn individually but not in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have multiple files and I want to do a for in loop to draw a single graph with data from each file. When I draw a single graph I use the following code:
`import os`
`from google.colab import files`

```
import cv2
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive')
os.getcwd()
cws=pd.read_csv('#9930.TXT',skiprows=22,names=['"Time"', '"Temp"','"TGA"'], sep="\t")
cws=cws.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce', downcast='float')
cws['"Temp"']=pd.to_numeric(cws['"Temp"'])
mass_percent=cws['"TGA"']/18.98*100
plt.scatter(cws['"Temp"'],mass_percent, label='cws')
plt.xlabel("Temperature (°C)")
plt.ylabel(" Mass loss (%)")
plt.legend()
plt.show
```

Now I wanted to do the same inside a for in loop and I use the following:

```
import os
from google.colab import files
import cv2
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive')
os.getcwd()

plt.xlabel("Temperature (°C)")
plt.ylabel(" Mass loss (%)")

for ruta in rutas:
  df=pd.read_csv(ruta,skiprows=22,names=['"Time"','"Temp"','"TGA"'],sep="\t")
  df['"Temp"']=pd.to_numeric(df['"Temp"'])
  df['"Time"']=pd.to_numeric(df['"Time"'])
  df['"TGA"']=pd.to_numeric(df['"TGA"'])
  df['mass_percent']=df['"TGA"']/18.98*100
  plt.plot(df['"Temp"'],df['Time'])

plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

But when I run this, a blank graph appears but no error appears.
I looked for the solution to this problem but nothing worked for me

Comment: Put `plt.figure()` before the loop (or don't use it at all).  You are creating a new figure here just before you show it!

Comment: And note there is really no reason for your strings to be doubly quoted.  I would remove ALL of the double quote marks from your loop.

Comment: I tried withour the plt.figure() line but still not showing anything.

Comment: I also tried removing all double quotations, still not working

Comment: my files' names are like #9930.TXT... could that be a problem?